# How can I format a gitlab-ci.yml file to HTML

Tags: gitlab-ci

The gitlab system has a CI file linter that allows to check `gitlab-ci.yml` files. It renders these files as a table with informative entries.
However, this rendering is not very robust. Does anyone know if there is a component that provides this service, I.e. a sensible HTML rendering of the CI file for documentation purposes?